# how to modify the height and width of a bitmap

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, mat

I am working on an Android app, And I put many pictures in Assets directory by categories. And I get a bitmap of a image using code below

```
InputStream in = getAssets().open(file);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
Bitmap board = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(board);
canvas.drawBitmap(bm,0,0,null);
```

And the width and height(pixel) of all my image files is 360x240， I want the Bitmap:board to be 960x720 when the images are read because I need convert the bitmap to a 960x720 Mat using OpenCV.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you even tried [searching on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitmap+to+mat+opencv&rlz=1C1GGRV_enAT791AT791&oq=bitmap+to+mat+opencv&aqs=chrome..69i57.5343j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) before posting the question? Or read the documentation? Or read the suggestions from stackoverflow when you wrote the question? Because if you did, you wouldn't post this question. Or are you a robot? If you are, then I would completely understand why you would do this!

Comment: I didnt make it clear in the question, my problem is actually much more complex, of course I searched it but no way out so I turn for help here. But now I avoid the problem and use another way to realize the function, so I never solve it and I don't want to waste more time so I didn't update the question, you know, the due is close.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [createScaledBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createscaledbitmap) :

```
Bitmap createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, 
                int dstWidth, 
                int dstHeight, 
                boolean filter)
```

> Creates a new bitmap, scaled from an existing bitmap, when possible.
>   If the specified width and height are the same as the current width
>   and height of the source bitmap, the source bitmap is returned and no
>   new bitmap is created.

Comment: Thanks, it may give me some help, by the way, how to do with parameter filter?

Comment: Short answer : a filter is a function that gives your image  smoother edges if applied, if you upscale your image, put it true to avoid a mosaic effect,(takes more time) I think (not sure) that the filter used is bilinear interpolation ->https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

Comment: I tried your method but it didn't work, it cannot fit to the size, I mean I don't want  a fixed scale but a fixed pixel

Comment: Did you get a Bitmap from the original one?